# Как сделать событие moseup, mousedown, click для телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Очевидно, что на телефоне нет мышки, чем заменить события moseup, mousedown, click для пользователей смартфонов?

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').mousedown(function(event) {
    var audio = $('audio')[0]
    audio.play()
    audio.currentTime = 0
});
    $('.button').mouseup(function(event) {
    var audio = $('audio')[0]
    audio.pause()
});
});
```

Например, эта функция не работает на смартфоне.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 1):

```
.mousedown == .touchstart
.mousemove == .touchmove
.mouseup  == .touchend
```

Если не сработает, то попробуй в начале методов писать on

```
.ontouchstart
.ontouchmove
.ontouchend
```

click  срабатывает как на компе, так и на телефоне
(попробуй написать onclick)

Удачи тебе